# Does the establishment of a legal upper speed limit on highways lead to a reduction in traffic deaths and accidents?

Tags: law, safety, traffic, driving-speed

The conventional wisdom is that established speed limits lead to an increase in safety.

> Speed limits are usually set to attempt to cap road traffic speed; there are several reasons for wanting to do this. It is often done with an intention to improve road traffic safety and reduce the number of road traffic casualties from traffic collisions. In their World report on road traffic injury prevention report, the World Health Organization (WHO) identify speed control as one of various interventions likely to contribute to a reduction in road casualties.
> [Wikipedia: Speed Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_limit)

I am inclined to question the conventional wisdom, especially when those proposing the restrictions have something to benefit by maintaining and enforcing restrictions (ticket revenues, enforcement disgression, etc).

To be clear, I am not talking about raising the speed limit.  I think the presence of any established limit has a psychological effect on people, who may actually drive faster than is safe if a sign says that it is permissible.  I am also not asking if driving a car too fast for conditions is dangerous, that seems pretty clear.  I am asking if establishing and posting a legal speed limit decreases the danger on highways.  I am also restricting this query to highways, since I believe that they are fundamentally different than surface and residential streets, and the data for each will be vastly different, so different conclusions may be reached.

Comment: Related but different question: [Is driving the speed limit on a highway safer?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4159/is-driving-the-speed-limit-on-a-highway-safer)

Comment: I suppose there are three cases: 1. A posted speed limit. 2. A legal speed limit which is not posted. 3. No speed limit at all. Which did you want to compare? The hard part of such a study would probably be finding a control.

Comment: In addition to what Nate's written, it would also help if you clarify whether you're asking about speed limits that are enforced or not, as this may make a significant difference to the answer.

Comment: I am mostly interested in cases 1 vs 3.  Case 2 is really a mix of 1 and 3

Comment: I feel that yes, it's possible to set a limit that's counter-productive by being too high and forcing some people to drive faster than they would drive otherwise. However, surely a very low limit cannot have this effect. So maybe clarify your question? Whether it does depends on how high it is.

Comment: romkyns, this line of questioning is examining the effects of setting a limit vs not setting a limit.  Is this clear enough?

Comment: romkyns, a very low limit can also be dangerous.  Suppose that you set the speed limit to 35 on the freeway, were most cars are likely able to travel at 75 miles per hour safely.  In this case you will likely have 75% of the population driving at 75 miles an hour, but with radar detectors and all other manner of countermeasures against enforcement.  So as these people are flying down the highway, they are coming up very fast on the small percentage that is traveling very slow, and occasionally there will be massive abrupt changes in speed as the speeders attempt to avoid the enforcers.

Comment: There was a good documentation on the German TV channel ZDF about the topic in 2015: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3UXYSL9R04 The conclusion they draw is that traffic deaths and and accidents indeed decrease with a speed limit and hence that a speed limit in Germany is overdue. The documentation considers other factors and spends a lot of time on the role of the car industry in the politics of the matter, so it is a bit hard to work out what the evidence is and what is speculation. Maybe someone else can watch it in more detail and promote this comment to an answer.

Comment: You should also note that some highways and interstates also have a minimum speed limit.

Comment: Maybe I'm overly sensitive to phrasing, but the way you're asking this - and the coments you've made above - imply that you believe the only *real* reason for speed limits is so that the (inherently nefarious) government can arbitrarily fine people who exceed it.

Comment: This is really two questions. As indicated in the quotations, *death* rates are reduced simply because of the severity of any collision.  There could be just as many collisions, but at slower speeds many of them will be survivable. ¶ But the question conflates this with so-called *accident* rates, which are not mentioned in the quotations.

Answer (score 31):

Germany is an interesting case to study this, as they have stretches of highway with and without speed limits. In a [study](https://brandenburg.de/cms/media.php/lbm1.a.2239.de/studie_tempolimit.pdf) done in the state of Brandenburg, the effect of putting a speed limit on stretches of highway has been studied by comparing the accident statistics before and after the new limit.

On two stretches the speed limit was changed from no limit to 130 km/h (~80 MPH) and the effects were quite remarkable.

> Die Zahl der Unfälle (P,SS) halbierte sich von 654 U/3 Jahre auf 337 U/3 Jahre nach Einführung der Geschwindigkeitsbegrenzung (-48 %). Die Zahl der Verunglückten sank
> deutlich von 838 auf 362 Verunglückte in 3 Jahren (-57 %).

This says that the number of accidents in the years after the new limit decreased by 48% whereas the number of people involved in accidents decreased by 57%. (This is illustrated in the report on figure 3.1 very clearly)

Of course this has to be put into relation to the general decrease of accidents on all highways, which they did by looking at a couple of reference stretches where there was no speed limit over the whole time.

> Der Rückgang zum Zeitraum 2000-2002
> entsprach 50 %. Die Kontrollgruppen zeigen im Durchschnitt einen Rückgang um 23,5 % für die zeitliche Entwicklung auf, so dass die Geschwindigkeitsbegrenzung zu einer
> Verminderung um 26,5 % beigetragen hat. Der Unterschied der UKRa zwischen den
> begrenzten und unbegrenzten Strecken lag 2006 ebenfalls bei 26,5 %.

This means that the decrease (this time of the cost per distance driven linked to the accident) was 50% on the stretches with the new speed limit while it was 23.5% on the reference samples and that thus 26.5% can be linked to the new speed limit.

Overall this leads to the conclusion that in this case, a speed limit did significantly decrease the number of accidents. However I admit that this is limited to the German context, especially since it only looks at those two stretches.

Comment: “this has to be put into relation to the general decrease of accidents on all highways”: not exactly. It has to be compared to *similar* highways, not *all* highways. The two roads of the study may be the ones that had a high number of accidents. It would also be interesting to see whether the study mentions or not if there were other measures taken, such as warning signs indicating that the highway is dangerous, additional separators between the lanes, etc.

Comment: Regression to the mean is a problem here, speed limits are not applied randomly but introduced on the basis of a perceived problem. The link to the study doesn't seem to work so I can't check whether they accounted for that.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko: AFAIK in Germany new speed limits are indeed put up where particular dangers are identified. This could be the road not being up to standard for the higher speed, *too many and/or too severe accidents* on that stretch of road, possibly also a measured or expected increase in traffic (inside towns also: new nursing home or kindergarden). What I do not know is whether there can be exceptions for the purpose of studies, nor whether it would be legal to postpone such measures in order to have matched case-control-pairs for a study when several such sites are identified.

Comment: Wrt. 2 German specialties should be mentioned: a) there's no general speed limit on highways, but a Richtgeschwindigkeit = recommended max of 130 km/h. The recommendation has legal consequences, e.g. in case of an accident, having been faster means being at least partially responisble for the accident. b) Trucks and trailers have a limit of 80 or 100 km/h. A speed limit on highways reduces the speed difference between the right (slow) and faster lanes, and AFAIK that difference has been identified as particularly dangerous.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko They did compare to similar highways. In the study 4 reference stretches were chosen, two of which have similar or higher accident rates as the stretch in question. It is all discussed in the study with quite a lot of details and all the data shown (tables 3.1 and 3.2)

Comment: @JackAidley Link is fixed, they did account for this as the references stretches that they are compared to are of similar nature. See tables 3.1 and 3.2 for instance.

Comment: @drat Thanks for fixing the link. The comparison to reference stretches does not control for regression to the mean, and I can't see anywhere in that study where they discuss that issue. There are natural limits on the kind of study that can be done on topics like this, so this is likely to be a problem with any such study.

Comment: The reduction in collisions could be explained by many of the vehicles switching to a different route, thereby reducing the number of vehicles using the highway. Or did the number of vehicles using the highway remain the same?

Comment: @RayButterworth: I can't see any data on that in the study, but given where these routes are, and the lack of faster alternatives, it does not seem a plausible explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Those are number from [work done by the IIHS in the US](https://www.iihs.org/topics/speed), this is an interesting read about speed limits in general and not just safety:

> Fatalities also went up. Deaths on rural interstates increased 25-30 percent when states began increasing speed limits from 55 to 65 mph in 1987 (Baum et al., 1991; Baum et al., 1989; Baum et al., 1990). In 1989, about two-thirds of this increase — 400 deaths — was attributed to increased speed and the rest to increased travel.

and

> An IIHS study examined longer-term changes. During 1993-2017, a 5 mph increase in the maximum state speed limit was associated with an 8 percent increase in fatality rates on interstates and freeways and a 3 percent increase on other roads (Farmer, 2019). In total, there were an estimated 37,000 more traffic fatalities during these years than would have been expected if maximum speed limits in 1993 had remained in place. In 2017 alone, there were more than 1,900 additional deaths.

The quoted research [The effects of higher speed limits on traffic fatalities in the United States, 1993–2017](https://www.iihs.org/api/datastoredocument/bibliography/2188) used different variables while comparing so to isolate other influencing factors. The results are

> A 5 mph increase in the maximum state speed limit was associated with an 8.5% increase in
> fatality rates on interstates/freeways and a 2.8% increase on other roads. In total during the 25-year study period,
> there were an estimated 36,760 more traffic fatalities than would have been expected if maximum speed limits had
> not increased—13,638 on interstates/freeways and 23,122 on other roads